# How to fix CORS policy issue with get request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors

please help me to solve CORS policy issue, it happens when I'm trying to make a get request to applications endpoint, and issue is only reproducible from http://localhost:8080/ on prod request works fine.

vue.config.js file

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'https://spinstatus.zenoss.io/'
    }
}
```

request method

```js
const grabApps = async () => {
  const res = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${spinnakerURL}/gate/applications`,
    withCredentials: false,
    crossdomain: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
  });
  return res.data || []
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIcUv.png)

[headers from localhost request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhalc.png)

[headers from prod request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlg62.png)

Comment: CORS headers have to be set by the **server** as part of the response.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the devServer configuration in `vue.config.js` like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer:
  {
    proxy:
    {
      '/gate':
      {
        target: 'https://spinstatus.zenoss.io',
        changeOrigin: true,
        onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res, options) =>
        {
          proxyReq.setHeader('Origin', 'https://spinstatus.zenoss.io');
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks, but that config is not working :(

Comment: I am using it in my projects - it definitely works. But the error says that your API server in dev is not returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header.

Comment: i see, ty for that